# GetFirst and GetNext call to fetch records from a persistent class

Tags: c++, oop

This is more of a design level question. I have a persistent class that queries records from DB through SQL query and returns to the caller through a member function called getNext(), the signature of the function is as below:

```
int getNext(); // returns 0 on failure and 1 on success
```

I don't have a getFirst() call. So, the caller typically runs a while loop to get the data, e.g.

```
while (obj.getNext() > 0) {
  obj.getValues(0;
  ...
}
```

Within getNext() implementation, if there is no data (first call) or no more data (last call in the while loop), I write "no data found" in the output and return 0, else retrieve the data and return 1.
Is there any clever way to know from within getNext() call that this is the first call (where no data means the query has no results) and this is non-first call within a loop where no data means the query has no more results to show, which is fine, so "no data found" will not be displayed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put a `bool firstCall` intitialized to `true` as a member of your class. At the end of `getNext()`, you can set `firstCall` to `false`. So it will be false for all successive calls of `getNext()`.

You can now show the correct output depending on `firstCall` value.

When a new query is performed, `firstCall` must be reset to `false`.